# Dictionary in Swift fails to convert to NSDictionary in Objective C when compiled (Expected a type)

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a Cocoa Touch Framework written in Swift that I am referencing in an Objective C project (iOS app).

The Swift framework has a protocol and class like so:

```
public protocol TestProtocol
{
    func configure (settings: Dictionary<String, Any>)
}

public class MyFramework: NSObject, TestProtocol
{
    @objc public func configure (settings: Dictionary<String, Any>)
    {
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to reference the framework in my Objective C project, I'm getting build errors on the compiled Swift class:

```
Expected a type
```

And when viewing the generated/compiled class (`MyFramework-Swift.h`), I see the error is on the following line:

```
- (void)configureWithSettings:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> * _Nonnull)settings;
```

It seems like the Swift to Objective C conversion is not working properly. If I comment out the method or change the function to have a different parameter, the error goes away.

Is there a way to advise the compiler on the type/generics for `Dictionary` to convert to `NSDictionary`?

Comment: have you tried using the bridging header for swift class into Objective C project, the Swift library cannot be directly called from Objective-C, since it is missing the required annotations in the code, and in many cases, modules do not inherit from NSObject, rather they use the native Swift data types. However, by using an intermediate helper class, it is possible to call the Swift library from Objective-C.